# What is the best way to add a custom 'TLD' to a webview in electron

Tags: node.js, electron

I have a webview in an electron app that serves webpages via some other elements like an address bar, or the inherent clicking of a link. I am making a browser that serves up real webpages and it works as it should, but I would like to find a way to add a custom TLD to the webview in electron.

e.g. https://kristconsole.kst -> looks up the a record at https://krist.ceriat.net/names/kristconsole, serves the page in the fake 'a' record and masks the url in that 'a' record to kristconsole.kst.

If the 'a' record is https://google.com/ then I want kristconsole.kst to be masked as the url, but I want it to display [https://google.com/'s](https://google.com/%27s) contents.

Perhaps there is some kind of proxy/dns that I can run through electron to add my fictional tld with masking to the site that actually serves the content.

What I have tried: I have tried listening to events on clicking and webpage switching on the webview, but it seems inefficient if there is another method that can just mask the URL.

Any help is very appreciated!
Fisher

**EDIT:** I should have added more information, the .kst TLD is the only one I want to add, as it is a fictional tld used in a project that me and some friends are doing. How it works is you use the fictional cryptocurrency to 'buy' these .kst domains, and I want to mask them over whatever url the user picks when they register/update the domain name.

Comment: Don't use a fictional TLD... people can register most anything these days.  Consider `.local` or similar.

Comment: @Brad I have amended my post to be a little more clear, what do you think of this? It's not for personal use or I'd just setup a hosts file. **EDIT:** host**s**

Comment: What would you do if someone registered `.kst` properly, later on?  Sounds disastrous, since you're selling something you don't actually have real claim to.

Comment: @Brad it's not going to be used commercially, it's a small project with some friends about a cryptocurrency that is used in minecraft. we won't worry about the creation of an actual .kst TLD being created, it's more of a hobby project. These are **fictional** domains as a reward for mining the fictional cryptocurrency.